# View aggregations programmatically

Tags: splist, aggregation, spview

I have a view in my list,
I defined aggregations in my view: sum and average of several columns.
Now I want to get **programmatically** the aggregations **results**.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation is not something that is calculated and stored but just defined type of aggregation required or to be done.
You need to calculate it your own. SharePoint displays the aggregated data by using XSLT.

Comment: Do you know how SharePoint perform this calculation? (And where to find it)

Comment: As I told you, since SharePoint uses XSLT so doing aggregation calculation using XSLT. XSLT is used to define how XML is to be rendered and formatted, like CSS for XHTML/HTML. I also required to do the calculation but ended up with calculating my own way in by enumerating through each list item.

Comment: Do you know where the calculation of SharePoint is? Which XSL file?

Comment: No I am not sure, you need to do some research on that, you can search on google or post a questions on same.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar case and I wasn't find solution for getting grouped result from list view. I write custom code on c# and LINQ with all aggregation and render data  on third-party grid component.